# JS. React. JSX проблемы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Всем привет!
Имеем 3 файла: `App.js`; `post-list.js`; `post-list-item`.
В файле `post-list-item` я прописал переменную `PostListItem`.
В файле `post-list.js` я создал переменную `PostList` и вложил список из переменной `PostListItem` - 3 шт.
В `App.js` я прописал `PostList`.
Проблема в том, что в браузере список из 3 шт. `PostListItem` отображается только 1 раз. Хотя по задумке должен все 3 раза.
Но если в `App.js` прописать `PostList` - 3 раза, то в браузере все 3 раза он появится.
Как сделать так, чтобы не прописывать в `App.js` 3 раза `PostList`, а отделаться только 1 разом?

```
PostListItem
import React from 'react';

const PostListItem = () => {
    return (
        <li className="app-list-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span className="app-list-item-label">
                Lady Gaga Paul Walker
            </span>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <button className="btn-star btn-sm">
                <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
            </button>

            <button className="btn-trash btn-sm">
                <i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
            </button>

            <i className="fa fa-heart"></i>

        </div>
        </li>
    )
}
export default PostListItem;
```

```
PostList
import React from 'react';

import PostListItem from '../post-list-item';

const PostList = () => {
    return (
        <ul className="app-list list-group">
            <PostListItem/>
            <PostListItem/>
            <PostListItem/>
        </ul>
    )
}

export default PostListItem;
```

```
import React from 'react';

import AppHeader from '../app-header';
import SearchPanel from '../search-panel';
import PostStatusFilter from '../post-status-filter';
import PostList from '../post-list';


const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <AppHeader/>
            <div className="search-panel d-flex">
                <SearchPanel/>
                <PostStatusFilter/>
            </div>
            <PostList/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно вывести PostListItem в цикле:

```
const PostList = () => {
    return (
        <ul className="app-list list-group">
            {[1, 2, 3].map(() => <PostListItem/>)}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: думаю у меня ошибка где-то. Должно получиться проще, но не пойму где я косякнул

Comment: @Vladislav4488 понятия не имею о чем вы, вот вам ваш код в песочнице, отрисовывается 3 раза https://codepen.io/MrYogurt/pen/gOvYdGM

Answer (score 0):

Я дебил.
В `PostList` я на экспорт кидаю `PostListItem`, а должен `PostList`, вот поэтому в браузере список только 1 раз появлялся.

Comment: Самокритично конечно =))) но хорошо что разобрались